# Two methods lead to different answers

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

**Question:**

> **Evaluate limit**
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan x}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(10^x-1)-(2^x-1)-(5^x-1)}{x\tan x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(10^x-1)/x-(2^x-1)/x-(5^x-1)/x}{\tan x}$$
Now using identity $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$, we get:

$$= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln 10-\ln5-\ln2}{\tan x}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln 1}{\tan x}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{\tan x}= 0$$

---

The answer however is obviously wrong. I have the correct solution in my school book. But **I wish to know why my solution is wrong.** I have consulted my classmates but none of them can see the problem here either.

Comment: Notice that $\tan(x)\to0$ as well, so you merely end up with $0/0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But isn't it something like `exact 0/approx 0`, which isn't indeterminate but instead equal to `exactly 0`? (`exact 0` comes from $\ln1$ in the numerator)

Comment: But you obtained $\ln 1$ using a limit.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Note you basically did this:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$$Can you spot the flaw now?

Comment: A better method could be to factorize the numerator.

Comment: Use this one: $$a^x-1\sim(x+\frac {x^2}2 \ln a)\ln a$$ for $x\to 0$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I get what you're saying. Since $\ln 1$ is from a limit, we can't put it exact 0. Now I've seen the flaw, but how do I correct it?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe That answer is in my book ;)

Comment: This is where you made a mistake, where you write as $$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(10^x-1)/x-(2^x-1)/x-(5^x-1)/x}{\tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln 10-\ln5-\ln2}{\tan x}.$$ Did you see it?

Comment: ΘΣΦGenSan and polfosol ok thanks I got it. One points the flaw the other corrects it :D

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan But, why can I NOT use the identity here?

Comment: There is no problem with the identity you mentioned. Its in the way you evaluate limits, as what I've have previously.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan So, what way should I've used? The one that polfosol mentioned?

Comment: The solution makes me feel it takes more than algebra to get to it, but of course I hope someone surprises me with a nice solution.

Comment: Well, you have to see the solution given in your school book or the one pasted below by @Simply Beautiful Art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the identity replacement; there are certain conditions under which it is legitimate.

Suppose $f(x) \sim g(x)$ in the sense that
$$
\lim f(x) = \lim g(x)
$$
or 
$$
\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}  = 1
$$

You cannot always substitute an equivalent $g$ for $f$, which tends to be wrong, even in simple cases. You may **absolutely not** use the identity, when $f$ is an addend.

For example, 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3} = \frac{1}{2}$ (verify!). But if you replace $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ with $x$, which are equivalent when x tends to zero, you get a wrong answer.

Now suppose $f\sim g, u\sim v$. You may substitute equivalents in the following cases:
$$\lim \frac{f}{g} = \lim\frac{u}{v}$$
$$\lim f^g = \lim u^v$$
Of course, you may verify, that

$$ \lim (\frac{1}{f})^g = \lim (\frac{1}{u})^v$$
and 
$$ \lim (1+f)^{\frac{1}{g}} = \lim (1 + u)^{\frac{1}{v}} $$
are all legitimate replacements.

You have to be careful.

Comment: Sir, you seem to be saying something meaningful, in regards to why replacing the identity did not work. But, this technique or law was never taught to us in school. Is there a name to this law (or technique) so I can look it up online?

Comment: This is more suited as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GaurangTandon It is called equivalent infinitesimal, I suppose.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think the question is about why the method is wrong.

Comment: I suppose it does go both ways...

Answer (score 2):

This may be solved with [Taylor approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).  Recall that

$$e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+\mathcal O(x^3)$$

It thus follows that

$$\frac{a^x-1}x=\ln(a)+\frac{\ln^2(a)}2x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

And

$$\frac{10^x-1}x-\frac{2^x-1}x-\frac{5^x-1}x=\left[\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(5)}2\right]x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

Now recall that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}x=1$, so

$$\begin{align}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan(x)}&=\frac{\frac{10^x-1}x-\frac{2^x-1}x-\frac{5^x-1}x}{\tan(x)}\\&=\frac{\left[\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(5)}2\right]x+\mathcal O(x^2)}{\tan(x)}\\&=\frac{\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(5)}2+\mathcal O(x)}{\frac{\tan(x)}x}\\&\to\frac{\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(5)}2+0}1\end{align}$$

> $$L=\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(5)}2$$
>   $$=\ln5\ln2$$